# AWS Node JS lambda connection to AWS RDS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am very new to AWS & NodeJS and require some help on the following. It would be great if anyone can guide me to the right direction.

**Requirement** - I need to develop a AWS lambda(NodeJS) which will connect to the AWS RDS(either Aurora/MySQL/Oracle)
**Twist** - This single lambda should be capable of connecting with all the three mentioned RDS without major change in code.

Is there any adapter / middleware (e.g. hibernate) available which can be used to achieve this ?

Pls let me know.

Thanks in advance!!

Regards,
Mousumi

Comment: Well you could use the same driver to connect to Aurora & MySQL as Aurora is MySQL compatible. I'm not aware of any driver that spans MySQL & Oracle as the connection works differently, let alone the SQL syntax (I've purposely said drivers, not middleware as to not get confused with things like express). It would be interesting to know more about your use case and restrictions, as I suspect there is a better design than what you are suggesting.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. AWS SDK have capabilities to connect with Aurora DB Instance , but what if in future I wish to migrate to Oracle DB Instance in AWS. Then I will have to change all my query written in MySQL to Oracle compatible format. I want to avoid this situation. Like in web applications we use hibernate which is independent of underlying DB. We only need to change the DB driver. Can something like this be achieved in AWS ? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Again, it would help to understand what you are trying to do. Are you specifically looking for an ORM? If so there is SWORM (see https://github.com/featurist/sworm), but that is only really useful for writes (reads are still in native SQL syntax).

Comment: Thanks again for you reply. Yes , I am looking for a ORM. Instead of writing DB compatible queries in NodeJS , I would like to use an ORM. My aim is to read / write /update queries between NodeJS and AWS Aurora (MySQL). Is there any other ORM apart from SWORN which has read capability ? Pls let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the further comments made by the author, they are looking for a Node.js ORM that works with both MySQL and Oracle drivers.

There don't appear to be many ORMs that fit that description and are also well supported (caveat - based purely on a few Google searches).

There is one I found that fits the description though and still appears to be actively supported and that is knex (see https://knexjs.org).

Comment: Thanks for guiding me in the right direction. I also searched about few more NodeJS ORM's. One of them being sequelize ,may serve my purpose. https://dzone.com/articles/sequelize-javascript-orm http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html

Comment: I looked at sequelize, but it doesn't appear to provide support for Oracle. There is a fork, which adds that support, called sequelize-oracle (https://github.com/adeo-proxideco/sequelize-oracle), but it no longer appears to be supported